# Is there a way to have a php script execute with a specific ip address

Tags: php

Is there way to have a php script that uses file_get_contents to utilize an ip address different than what the server's ip address is?  We have 5 ip addresses and want to utilize a specific one for this purpose.

Comment: @skrilled I believe OP wants to change the origin IP of the `file_get_contents`'s request.

Comment: Execute the call from the machine that has the IP you want...

Comment: Oh, I get it now. My bad on reading things too fast. This is still something that's answered in the documentation though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You have to configure the stream context you want to use though.

```
<?php
// context options
$ctxopts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '192.168.0.100:0',
    ),
);

// create the context...
$context = stream_context_create($ctxopts);

// ...and use it to fetch the data
echo file_get_contents('http://www.example.com', false, $context);
```

You can get more info on http://php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) that is easily accessible on php.net

```
context
A valid context resource created with stream_context_create(). If you don't need to use a custom context, you can skip this parameter by NULL.
```

[stream_context_create()'s documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) explains the rest

```
$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '123.123.123.123:0', // 0 for automatically determine port
    )
);
```

final code:

```
$opts = array(
    'socket' => array(
        'bindto' => '123.123.123.123:0', // 0 for automatically determine port
    )
);    
$stream = stream_context_create($ctxopts);
echo file_get_contents('http://www.website', false, $stream);
```